# How can I read the log of a Subversion repository without checking the repository out locally?

Tags: svn

I would like to be able to view file diffs between revisions, but not check the full project out.

Client-wise, I have access both to Tortoise SVN and Smart SVN.

Answer (score 4):

Use "Repository Browser" in TortoiseSVN. Enter the URL of your repository. Navigate to the file you are interested in. Right click the file and choose "Show log" menu item. In there, holding the Ctrl key, select 2 revisions you want to compare. Right click will give you "Compare revisions" menu item. Just choose that and you will see the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

And you have access to a web browser.  If you are wanting to view files and attributes of a subversion repository then you should be able to access it through the URL you are connecting to in your subversion client.